# Create a file of pairs from pairs

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Say I have the following file:

```
A 1
B 2
CC 33
```

And I want to create a file containing every combination of two from the previous file, like this:

```
AA 11
AB 12
ACC 133
BA 21
BB 22
BCC 233
CCA 331
CCB 332
CCCC 3333
```

Can this be done with bash, for an arbitrary file? Each entry can consist of any characters except for newline and space. UTF-8 characters will be included in some entries.

I don't care about order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this with `awk` reading file twice:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { m[$1] = $2; next; } { for (i in m) { print $1 i, $2 m[i]; } }' file file
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this entirely within the shell:

```
while read -r f1 f2
do
    while read -r f3 f4
    do
        printf "%s %s\n" "$f1$f3" "$f2$f4"
    done < your_file
done < your_file
```

You say,
"Each entry can consist of any characters except for newline and space." 
If you really mean that entries can contain tab characters,
say `IFS=" " read` instead of `read` (both times).

**The “fine print”:**

A command like `read f1 f2`
will read the first “word” on the line of input into variable `f1`
and *the rest of the line* into `f2`.  For example,
the input `The quick brown fox`
would result in `f1="The"` and `f2="quick brown fox"`. 
If you’re sure that your file will never have three (or more) columns
(i.e., never have more than two words on any line),
then there’s nothing to worry about. 
If you’re happy with everything that’s not part of the first word
being treated as part of the second word,
then the above code should be OK.

But, if you want `The quick brown fox` to be treated as `f1="The"`
and `f2="quick"`, with `brown fox` being discarded (ignored),
then add a third variable to each of the `read` commands. 
E.g., `f1 f2` would become `f1 f2 x`;
this will result in `f1="The"`, `f2="quick"`, and `x="brown fox"`. 
Simply by not using `$x`, we discard the input after the second word. 
The second `read` can similarly be changed to `read -r f3 f4 x` —
since we’re not using `$x`, it doesn’t matter if we overwrite it. 
If you’d rather use a different throwaway variable — e.g., `… f3 f4 y` —
that’s OK, too.

The `read` command, by default,
treats the backslash (`\`) character specially. 
Basically, backslash followed by any other character
merge into a special version of the second character. 
Thus, `\C\C` would be read as `CC`. 
But, more importantly,
backslash followed by space is not treated as a word separator,
and backslash followed by newline (i.e., a backslash at the end of a line)
is not treated as a line separator/terminator. 
When we invoke `read` with the `-r` option,
that stops, and backslash becomes an ordinary character. 
Here are some practical examples of the differences:

```
            Without -r (default)                  __ With -r __
_Input_         f1        f2                      f1         f2
A\B\\C          AB\C                              A\B\\C
D\ E F          D E       F                       D\         E F    (or f2="E" and x="F")
G\          (this doesn’t count as a line)        G\
H               GH                                H
```

So I’ve added `-r` flags to my first version of my answer. 
If you want to be able to handle `D\ E` as a single word, don’t use `-r`.

Comment: It depends on both files synchronizing exactly - an additional blank line in either file during operation breaks this. If you want to treat variable length records like fixed-length records - which is what you do you compress delimiters - you should try to block them out first somehow - maybe `conv=sync,block` them with `dd`, for example. I also think `xargs` would be better suited here - you can get more specific about record length/size distributions, which is not to mention it would probably be a lot faster. But I would use `paste` - this is its job.

Answer (score 1):

To preserve the order and avoid reading the file twice, I'd do:

```
awk '{f1[NR] = $1; f2[NR] = $2}
     END {
       for (i = 1; i <= NR; i++)
        for (j = 1; j <= NR; j++)
          print f1[i]f1[j], f2[i]f2[j]
     }' file
```

Now, that stores the whole file's content in memory before processing it (like in [@taliezin's approach](/a/203782)). If you'd rather not do that, then you'd need to read the file as many times as the file has lines like in [@G-Man's approach](/a/203799). But using `awk` instead of `sh`/`bash` ([which is not designed for that](/q/169716)) would be a lot more efficient:

```
 awk '{f1=$1; f2=$2
       while ((getline < "file") > 0) print f1$1, f2$2
       close("file")}' file
```